# How to use pre-compiled header on VC++19?

Tags: visual-c++, precompiled-headers

Hello after I've upgraded visual studio to 19 now if I create a C++ project it works fine but I cannot set using "pre-compiled headers" on the beginning of creating project like in visual studio 2015.

If I create a project then maybe I should do some settings to create pre-compiled header.

- How could I create and use pre-compiled headers? Thank you.

Comment: Hi guys anybody home?

Answer (score 0):

The default precompiled header in Visual Studio used to be `stdafx.h` the default name has been changed to `pch.h`, you can include that.
to enable pre-compiled header files, go to `project>properties>C/C++>precompiled headers`

Comment: It doesn't work. No file there "pch.h". and the default file in settings is "stdafx.h".